# How can I "mouse swipe" with plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, mouseevent

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to "master" it somehow and in order for me to do so I don't want to use any library [like jQuery] yet.

That being said, I have found several ways to implement a **"mouse swipe"** with just Javascript like: [Simulate swipe with mouse in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894458/simulate-swipe-with-mouse-in-javascript).
But the answers are always very shallow in the posts that I have found.

Even tho, all of the solutions point to: mousedown -> mousemove -> mouseup events. Which is what I'm doing.

I set up an exercise for my self to "master" the bases of Javascript: I would have to create a flat and cross-browser-compatible interface that would allow me to save notes (in local storage) **using only Javascript**, css3 and html5 (the hard part is the cross browser compatibility).

So I thought of a simple table with 2 columns: to save the title of the note (first column) and the note (second column). i.e.

[image]

What matters is the table at the end. I want to be able to "mouse-swipe" the rows of the table.

This is what I have come up to (I'm not going to put all the code, just the basics of what I got):

First: the table is a set of classes through CSS;

```
/*CSS*/
div.table {
    display: table;
}
div.table .row{
    display: table-row;
}
div.table .row .col, div.table .row .col-2{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Second: the html;

```
<div id="savedNotesTable" class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Testing</div>
        <div class="col-2">This is a test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Testing</div>
        <div class="col-2">This is a test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Testing</div>
        <div class="col-2">This is a test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Last but not least: the Javascript

```
function addEvent(element, type, fn){ 
    // custom add event function that cares about compatibility
    // returns fn
}

function removeEvent(element, type, fn){ /*custom remove event function that cares about compatibility and removes only the specific handler*/ }

function addSwipe(element, parent){
    addEvent(element, "mousedown", function(e){
        var mouseupHandler = addEvent(document, "mouseup", mouseUpHandler);
        var mousemoveHandler = addEvent(document, "mousemove", function(e){
            // element.style.position = "static";
            // parent.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
            // add transition and blur to the element
            // mouseSwipe = absolute value of(originalPosition of mouse - e.pageX)
        });

        function mouseUpHandler(e){
            // pseudocode:
            // if mouseSwipe >= 50%(div size) = delete from the parent which is the "table"
            //  transition and blur OUT to 100% and delete
            // if mouseSwipe < 50%(div size) = don't delete
            //  transition back to 0% and unblur.

            removeEvent(document, "mousemove", mousemoveHandler);
            removeEvent(document, "mouseup", mouseupHandler);
        };
    });     
};

// this is just to add them to the test notes on the html
// The real thing is going to add the swipe when I save the new element
var table = document.getElementById("savedNotesTable");
var notes = table ? table.childNodes : undefined;
for(var prop in notes){
    if(prop != "length" && notes.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        if(notes[prop].nodeName != "#text"){
            addSwipe(notes[prop], table);
        };
    };
};
```

Am I doing it right? Or is there another way I'm not seeing?
I was able to get somewhere messing with the position of the divs like position="absolute" inside the onmousedown event but that messed with the width and length of the table row.

I'm looking for best practices also.

Comment: You may be interested in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. I read this looking for an error but it seems you are looking for improvements or code that isn't right. stackoverflow.com is more for asking how to fix issues. codereview.stackexchange.com is more for.. well.. Code reviews. If you have a specific error that you need help with let me know but I am not going to read the entire project looking for fixes unless I am on codereviews.

Comment: Get jQuery and just use `.on("swipe",function(){ });`

Comment: @ManofSnow his update states he doesn't want to use libraries... He specifically named jQuery. :)

Comment: Also. "mouse swipe" can be misleading. I think that is what lead to Man of Snow's comment which is for swiping on mobile devices. It looks like you are dragging elements so you should probably say "mouse drag" because that is more commonly to heard when dealing with "mousedown -> mousemove -> mouseup".

Comment: @DutGRIFF Right, and the code above doesn't seem fullproof;  I would set a timer so they have a limited time to swipe.  That answers `If somehow the question is incomplete`

Comment: Thank you all for replying.
@DutGRIFF I actually posted some in codereview and it was put on hold so I deleted it from there.
I named it "mouse swipe" because I just want to swipe left or right, not drag it and drop it (to avoid confusion).
And also I don't understand what you mean with 'full proof'. I am just trying to do the swipe thing and then I was going to fix it so it runs smooth (I wouldn't want you to fix every problem I've got) ;)

Comment: @ManofSnow I know the solution is very straight forward with jQuery but I want to "master" the basics of JavaScript which include events.

Answer (score 4):

Just a remark about event handlers dynamic attribution

As long as your element is not destroyed, there is no need to remove the event handlers attached to it (unless you want to change the element's behaviour completely, but that's rather uncommon).

Adding and removing event handlers is relatively costly, and can lead to small memory leaks in some cases. It's usually simpler and safer to leave the handlers in place and modify them (slightly) to work in all cases.

I also think it makes the code more readable, by putting all the event binding in one place, and forcing the handlers to behave properly in all cases. But that's a matter of personal taste.

Here the problem is with mousemove, that will fire even when you're not dragging (i.e. when the mouse button is not depressed).

You can handle that like so (simplified code just to demonstrate the principle) :

```
function onMouseDown () {
    dragging = true;
}

function onMouseMove () {
    if (!dragging) return; // skip dragging action if mouse button not depressed
    // do your dragging stuff
}

function onMouseUp () {
   dragging = false;
   // do your end of dragging stuff
}

// handlers bound to the element only once
addEvent (element, 'mousedown', onMouseDown);
addEvent (element, 'mousemove', onMouseMove);
addEvent (element, 'mouseup'  , onMouseUp);
```

Comment: It might not be the answer I'm looking for, but it is definitely something I did not think before, thanks!