# Swiping a div with jQuery on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, mobile, swipe

I'd like to swipe a div to the left with jQuery.

I have tried with the swipe method of jQuery Mobile, but I want to really move the div to the left, like the native swipe function of iOS.
Can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603157/detecting-iphone-swipe-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Core jQuery doesn't have anything special for touch events, but you can easily build your own using the following events

- touchstart
- touchmove
- touchend
- touchcancel

For example, the touchmove

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    alert(touch.pageX + " - " + touch.pageY);
}, false);
```

This works in most webkit based browsers (incl. android).

[Apple documentation for handling events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

Comment: And so how can I move a div to the left according to the time and speed of the touch?

Comment: Here's something really simple for what you are effectively trying to achieve: http://css-tricks.com/slide-to-unlock. you just just need to play with the JS to make it do what you want.